# How to use re.findall or re.search to get the matches not found

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string that can be:

```
test = 'Something Else ( neW ) other and another (nEw ) with (nEw ) '
```

I need to get:

```
result = 'Something Else  other and another  with  '
```

But the best I've achieved so far is:

```
 import re
 f = re.findall(ur'\(\s*[nN][eE][wW]\s*\)',test)
 for i in f: test = test.replace(i,'')
```

How to using `findall` to get the part of the string NOT matching the searching pattern?

Comment: You can simplify the `[nN][eE][wW]` part a lot by using `re.IGNORECASE` (also spelled `re.I`).  Of course this affects the entire pattern, but in this case, that's fine, as there are no other alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = 'Something Else ( neW ) other and another (nEw ) with (nEw ) '
>>> re.sub(r'\(\s*[nN][eE][wW]\s*\)','',test)
'Something Else  other and another  with  '
```